# How to modify the last-position-jump vimscript to not do it for git commit messages

Tags: vim

Here's the script for convenience:

```
" Uncomment the following to have Vim jump to the last position when                                                       
" reopening a file
if has("autocmd")
  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$")
    \| exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
endif
```

The feature is excellent but not when used with certain cases where Vim is invoked as editor: For instance often I write a two line git commit message so the next time I commit it's gonna drop me on the second line and I have to adjust for this.

Similarly many other systems allow you to specify Vim to be used as an editor as part of some process that involves editing a file.

How can we detect this and modify our last-position-jump script? Git's actually kind of special because it uses the `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` file which stays the same across commits which is why this is happening. With a temp file it wouldn't occur on files that Vim hasn't seen before.

This probably makes the task nearly trivial (augment the script with a check if current file == `COMMIT_EDITMSG`...)

But, a really perfect answer is if we can detect whether Vim is invoked from the command line or if it was opened by a script. Is there a way to tell? I know unix programs can determine if they are running in a term/pseudoterm or not, though either way they do end up receiving input from the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the global rule (like in FDinoff's answer) with all sorts of exceptions, you can also undo the jump by putting the following into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim`:

```
:autocmd BufWinEnter <buffer> normal! gg0
```

Though I haven't experienced any problems with the above command, even on buffer switches, a more robust version makes the autocmd *fire once*:

```
augroup DisableLastPositionJump
    autocmd! BufWinEnter <buffer> execute 'normal! gg0' | autocmd! DisableLastPositionJump BufWinEnter <buffer>
augroup END
```

Comment: I guess this will switch it back to line 0 if I happen to make a new buffer window? and switch back? I guess that's fine. **Edit:** Nevermind, I read the help for BufWinEnter, it's perfect.

Comment: The autocmd indeed re-executed, but somehow this never repositioned the cursor for me; I've added a more robust (but longer) version to the answer, but the one-liner should work, too.

Comment: Same works for `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/gitrebase.vim` :)

Answer (score 2):

Git commit messages have the filetype `gitcommit`.

Just add a check to see if the file is not of the `gitcommit` filetype for deciding when to jump to the last position.

```
if has("autocmd")
  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") && &filetype != "gitcommit"
    \| exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
endif
```

Comment: Looks like this does not work on my Mac - my cursor not always at the first line.

Comment: AFAIK this works. I’ve had In my vimrc for a while for both Linux and mac.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want VIM to remember where you were from the previous commit, set the following in `~/.vimrc`:

`autocmd FileType gitcommit call setpos('.', [0, 1, 1, 0])`

Source: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Always_start_on_first_line_of_git_commit_message

Comment: I put `if empty(getline(1)) | call setpos('.', [0, 1, 1, 0]) | endif` in my `ftplugin/gitcommit.vim` so that the cursor position is restored only on a fresh commit and not when I am, for example, amending a previous commit where I probably want to continue typing from where I left off.

Comment: I want to go to the top even in those amend cases. The problem is that what typically happens to me is that vim remembers some random position I was in some *other* commit message edit, which has nothing to do with the current commit.